# I got 404 error when try to install chrome on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: command-line, 16.04

---

when I ran this command to install google chrome browser on ubuntu 16.04:

```
$ wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

I got this error:

```
https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
Resolving dl.google.com (dl.google.com)... 172.217.23.142, 2a00:1450:4009:810::200e
Connecting to dl.google.com (dl.google.com)|172.217.23.142|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2020-06-25 23:54:06 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Comment: Google have removed the download directory & everything in it. Where did you get link? I still see it available via https://www.google.com/chrome/

Comment: No the link works.wget in my system can download it.So can firefox .It's probably a problem with your ISP or so.I don't know.